# Retrieve Maximum Display Resolution In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I know how to retrieve current display resolution in vb.net. We can use Screen.Bounds method. But I don't want to retrieve current resolution. I want to get the maximum resolution that the display supports.

Be it 1366*768 or 1920*1080. WMI also doesn't seem to have the answer.

Any help will be appreciated.